# cambiar formato de fecha en php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, date, datetime

tengo un codigo donde ingreso una fechas especificas que subi con un formtato en pdf el caso es que el formato tiene que se en plan

> Noviembre 20,2017

pero al insertar las fechas y llamarlas al pdf me quedan asi

> 2017-11-20

hay alguna forma de  cambiar el formato

PD: ya he mirado  aqui mismo en esSO pero las preguntas no coinciden

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo donde estas mostrando la fecha?

Comment: [clic aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) acá puedes encontrar información bastante útil de crear formatos personalizados a tus fechas

Comment: el pdf? o donde inserto la fecha a la DB

Comment: porque lo estoy guardando como string por que no se como guardarlo como date porque si lo guardo asi me suelta la fecha de hoy asi que lo guardo como string y en el modal pongo tipo date y asi se guarda

Comment: ¿Con qué herramienta generas el pdf?, tal vez allí haya un modo de darle formato

Comment: con dompdf lo genero

Comment: Añade tu código por favor para que nos hagamos una idea de como lo estas haciendo. Guardar las fechas en la BD como texto no es recomendable ya que dificulta mucho el tratamiento del dato entre otros.

Comment: si pero es que si lo guardo como date no se como guardalos datos que ponga y no los del dia presente